# Primefaces graphicImage only show the image the first time it loads

Tags: image, primefaces, jsf-2, rendering

Environment:

- Primefaces 10
- JSF 2.3

I am trying to load a profile image on a template jsf page, the first load works fine an the image appear but when I move to another page image dissapears.
The image is loaded on session scoped bean when session is created.
I also tried to upload with bytes array but same result.

Any idea what the problem is?

**index.xhtml**

```
<p:graphicImage id="img" value="#{sessionBean.imgProfile}"/>
```

**SessionBean.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {
    ...
    private StreamedContent imgProfile;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Methods
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ...

        Document d = getUsuari().getDocImatge();
        imgProfile = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                .stream(d::getInputStream)
                .contentType(d.getTipus())
                .name(d.getFileName())
                .build();
        ...
    }
    
    public StreamedContent getImgProfile() {
        return imgProfile;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like you bean is not really session scoped, maybe there's an issue with the import. Can you check if it's the right one? I cannot see your import but this is a possible problem.

Answer (score 1):

You currently need to create a new DefaultStreamedContent each time in your getter.
We will fix this for 11.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7730